# name of the android:drawable bookmark/favorites icon

Tags: android, icons, drawable

I was browsing through the platforms android-7, android-8  folder of the SDK to find the "official" bookmark/favorites icon, which I want to use in my app.
To my surprise I did not find it?
Does anybody know the name of it?
I would also need the name of the "add favorite/bookmark" and "remove favorite/bookmark" icon.

I dont want to design an icon, because my app uses only system icons so far, and I would like to stick to them to maintain a common look and feel across all icons and all API levels...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Browsing through the android-8 res folder, I cam across `btn_star_big_off_*.png` and `btn_star_big_on_*.png` with lots of different drawables for different states. You could use that for both adding and removing bookmarks.

Comment: Saw them too. They would be an alternative, while a star is not as descriptive as the coomon bookmark icons for favorites

Comment: Do you see this icon in many different apps? It's possible it's only used in whatever app you are seeing them in, thus not available globally through the SDK.

Comment: Not many, but a few. Is difficult to judge, because the design of the icons slightly changed through the different android version.

Comment: There is actually a discussion thread in the google android group about pro and cons of having more consistent and complete icon sets included in Android, as Apple does that on the iPhone. Google prefers to give the Developers the freedom to design their on icon sets. Personally I would wish for more complete icon sets (which then would be "automatically" updated, if a user upgrades his Android version). What I do now, is to copy the system icons from the SDK, design the missing ones, and have the drawback of not been getting updated automatically. This ensures consistency throughout the app.